# C Struct - field has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, incomplete-type

In my header file I have this

```
    typedef struct _client_value
{
    int client_id;
    struct timeval t;
    size_t size;
    char value[0];
} client_value;
```

I already included `<time.h>` but when I compiled, it said: `field 't' has incomplete type struct timeval t`.

I don't understand how this could happen.

Comment: include `sys/time.h`, not `time.h`

Comment: Thank you, guys. It seems to solve my problem. Silly me.

Comment: `char value[0];` is not C compliant code, although it may "work" with some compilers.

Comment: What's a better way to do that? It was part of the libpaxos I found online. Not sure what it means.

Comment: Using `char value[0];` is a variation on the 'struct hack' which was rendered obsolete by _flexible array members_ added to C99 and written `char value[];` — no dimension at all on the array.  The classic 'struct hack' uses `char value[1];` — GCC and compilers emulating it support `char value[0];` but the C standard doesn't (and the standard never did officially support the struct hack — but it always worked because compiler writers are realists).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It irks me that the Standard mandated that compilers regard size zero arrays as a constraint violation, given that the only thing many compilers would have needed to do to support semantics better than those of Flexible Array Members would have been to remove the code that squawks at attempts to define a size-zero array.

Comment: @supercat: You may be as irked as you wish — but there is little point in being irked unless you plan to do something about it, like join the standards committee and propose that zero-size arrays are beneficial.  You've got prior art in the GCC compiler which should simplify it.  C doesn't think anything is zero sized.  I'm not convinced that making an exception for arrays would help people.

Answer (score 5):

Its `#include <sys/time.h>`